# Twitter says that the "status is duplicated" but it isn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots

I'm trying to create an twitter bot which says good morning and good night every day to my girlfriend, but I'm deepening with this code: 187 error

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const Twitter = require('twitter')
const CronJob = require("cron").CronJob

dotenv.config({ path: './config.env'});

const twitterClient = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY,
    access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET
});

const tweet_bomdia = async () => 
    twitterClient.post('statuses/update', {status: 'bom dia @nalinhane, boa aula hoje ❤️'},  function(error, tweet, response) {
        if(error) throw error;
})

const tweet_bomdia_segunda = async () => 
      twitterClient.post('atualizando', {status: 'bom dia @nalinhane, boa semana e boa aula hoje ❤️'},  function(error, tweet, response) {
          if(error) throw error;
})

const tweet_bomdia_quarta = async () => 
      twitterClient.post('statuses/update', {status: 'bom dia @nalinhane, aguenta que já chegamos no meio da semana ❤️'},  function(error, tweet, response) {
          if(error) throw error;
})

const tweet_bomdia_sexta = async () => 
      twitterClient.post('statuses/update', {status: 'bom dia @nalinhane, sextooooooouuu bebe ❤️'},  function(error, tweet, response) {
          if(error) throw error;
})

const tweet_bomdia_fds = async () => 
      twitterClient.post('statuses/update', {status: 'bom dia @nalinhane, aproveite seu dia ❤️'},  function(error, tweet, response) {
          if(error) throw error;
})

const tweet_boanoite = async () => 
      twitterClient.post('statuses/update', {status: 'boa noite @nalinhane , durma bem ❤️'},  function(error, tweet, response) {
          if(error) throw error;
})

const job0 = new CronJob("0 7 * * 2,4", () => {
    console.log('Bom dia sendo enviado!')
    tweet_bomdia()
})

const job1 = new CronJob("0 7 * * 1", () => {
    console.log('Bom dia de segunda sendo enviado!')
    tweet_bomdia_segunda()
})

const job2 = new CronJob("0 7 * * 3", () => {
    console.log('Bom dia de quarta sendo enviado!')
    tweet_bomdia_quarta()
})

job0.start()
job1.start()
job2.start()
```

And this is the error:

```
F:\Projetos\Laura Bot\bot.js:21
          if(error) throw error;
                    ^
[ { code: 187, message: 'Status is a duplicate.' } ]
```

I really tried everything you can imagine and didn't help.

I've tried to switch the twitter API but it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter doesn’t allow duplicate content.

```
{
  "detail": "You are not allowed to create a Tweet with duplicate content.",
  "type": "about:blank",
  "title": "Forbidden",
  "status": 403
}
```

So, before creating a new tweet, you can delete the previous one.
Calling destroy `statuses/destroy/:id` API.

Or you can add a unique id for each tweet.

```
  bom dia @nalinhane, boa aula hoje ❤️ #00001
  bom dia @nalinhane, boa aula hoje ❤️ #00002
```

Comment: I would put this after or before the "quotation marks"?

Like:

`
"bom dia @nalinhane, boa aula hoje ❤️" #00001
`

Or:


´"bom dia @nalinhane, boa aula hoje ❤️ #00001"´


Thanks

Comment: @ALRCRUZ it doesn’t matter where you put it. What is important is each tweet will be unique. Also, if the answer helped, please upvote